# How to get the Vtype of the vehicle that sent the message?

Tags: omnet++, simulator, veins, sumo

I want to get the vtype of the vehicle that I am messaging with veins.
I could find "bsm->getSenderPos()" to get the sender's position, but I don't know how to get the Vtype.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me.
Thank you very much.

If I were to create it myself, would I have to create a function like "SendVtype" in the "DemoSafetyMessage.msg" file and get the "traciVehicle->getTypeId()"?